# Recovering the original input vector

Tags: matrices

Say i have a transformed vector
Is it possible to recover the original input vector without applying an inverse transformation?
If so how?

in the below image, i wish to recover the input vector [x,y]

I have seen from some lectures that you multiple the Transformed x ordinate from the transformed vector with the x coordinates of the transformation matrix + Transformed y ordinate with the y ordinates of the transformation matrix

I dont think this works tho...

EDITED LECTURE NOTES:
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm4zU.png)

Comment: You can solve the system of linear eqn using cramer's generalised rule

Comment: You are saying that given the transformed vector $\bar{v}=Av$, the original vector $v$ can be recovered by the application of the transformation again, i.e. $v = A\bar{v}=A( Av )$. Unless $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$, I don't see how $v=A^{2}v$ can hold. Anyways, this doesn't work for a general vector. Btw. why don't you want to use the inverse transformation? In the example you gave it can be easily found. Maybe edit your question and give an example where you can't use the inverse to help other people understand your problem better.

Comment: I am reading from lecture notes, but i think the idea is totally incorrect but i will edit my question soon and you can take a look, i will update here thank you for your help

Comment: Oskarryn i updated with the lecture notes, can you check please

Comment: Hopefully my writing is not too shabby :D

Comment: Use @username to mention people. Also, use Latex to type math - it increases the chance of getting a response. Check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @oskarryn The lecture notes are wrong i guess? only thing i can think of it the rotation matrix is orthogonal so multiplication by the transpose will give the original vector